# Execution failed for task app:compileDebugAidl: aidl.exe finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aidl

I am trying to build my project with AIDL example. But I keep getting this error:

```
:app:compileDebugAidl
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.
internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Users\xuefu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aidl.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 3
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

below is my build file and I am using Android Studio 1.3.2, Gradle 1.3.0 under the windows 8.1 x64 platform:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.crazyit.service"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the aidl.exe tool directly with the -p argument, to see if it prints any additional error messages outside of Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

Please check your aidl files, make sure all the files include the package name. e.g.

```
package com.zebra.gogogo;
parcelable GoInfo;
```